# What is the cause of so many Swift questions getting tagged with Objective-C?

Tags: discussion, bug, suggested-tags

I am seeing a lot of Swift/iOS related questions from low rep users where the questions are tagged with both [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) and [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c).

All of the code in the question is written in Swift. Most of these questions make no mention of Objective-C.

Is it possible that SO is suggesting the Objective-C tag just because it is an iOS question? If so, can we get that fixed?

Comment: No, there is no such suggestion.  Questioners tend to cast a wide net to hope to get as many readers as possible.  I suppose they don't yet know it is gauche.

Comment: interestingly if you make a fake question, and then start entering the tag `ios` in fact it does automatically suggest `swift` as a tag.  (Which is kind of odd.)  Perhaps in some circumstances it automatically suggests objective-c as a tag (perhaps if certain other cocoa-related items are mentioned?)

Comment: To those voting to close this as primarily opinion based, please keep in mind that I do ask a simple, concrete question at the end. This is not meant to ask why people are choosing to add the Objective-C tag. It's asking if SO is suggesting or adding the tag as the question is being written.

Comment: Even if it were asking the question in the title, "[brainstorm](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brainstorming) solutions to this problem on the main site" seems just fine for a meta question.

Comment: I updated the title to keep people from voting to close without actually reading the question.

Comment: @rmaddy Not even sure why that close option exists on meta. Isn't the entire (almost entire) point of meta to have discussions and hear opinions?

Comment: @rob kind of agree with you there, but generally when I see the close reason used it is to close the questions that really can't go anywhere productive.

Comment: Go ask the Tavern about using both the C and C++ tags on a question.  I think they might have a few suggestions as to why people do this.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick informal test, starting but not saving questions including different initial tags, code blocks with one language or the other in the body, and so on.  I did not observe SO making a language tag suggestion for either language.

Notwithstanding SO's tag defaulting behavior, I think it's appropriate in many instances to tag a question with both tags.  Consider the large number of questions predominantly about how to get something done with the SDK (iOS, MacOS etc.) or the platform (iPhone, Mac, TV, etc).  Answers to such questions are going to be right or wrong independent of the OP's or answerer's preferred dialect, and mostly readable by the OP and future readers.

One's reaction to such instances might be to leave the language tag out altogether and tag only with the SDK/platform, but both tags' definitions say something to the effect:

> question about the language features or requiring/depending on code in the language