# Should [swift] and [objective-c] tags never be used together?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076815/how-to-to-find-the-height-of-a-single-line-of-text-using-text-kit) using the tags [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) [textkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textkit)

However, the [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) and [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tags were edited out. I'm fine with that because I can see how the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag covers them both already. Also, the editor ([rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy)) is a high rep user with gold badges in [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) so this user obviously know what they are doing. A month ago rmaddy even asked the meta question [What is the cause of so many Swift questions getting tagged with Objective-C?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312773/what-is-the-cause-of-so-many-swift-questions-getting-tagged-with-objective-c) (but is as yet unanswered).

So I want to know, should I never double tag these languages as long as I use the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag? I'm not really sure because, to my thinking, there may be some advantage to including the language tags in addition to the platform. For example

- Some people who could answer the question may not be following [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)
- Lets the question be searchable by both [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) and [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).
- Explicitly shows that both Objective-C and Swift answers are acceptable.
- Although possibly superfluous, the extra information does not falsely represent the content of the question.

Comment: (While it may be an advantage for you to get more eyes on your question) it's not an advantage for people who are specifically looking to answer questions about either language.  Rather, it's a bit misleading, since there's no specific Swift (or Objective-C) question to answer.

Comment: But (if there is an answer at all) the question could be specifically answered in Swift *or* Objective-C. (It is possible that my specific question can't be answered because I misread the documentation, but there are other questions could be answered specifically in either language.)

Comment: *'ios tag covers them both already,'* No, it does not. What if the question is about MacOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with rmaddy's edit, and here's why.

Language tags should be used when knowledge of the language is *essential* to understanding the problem and its solution. [They say "this question is about **something in this language**"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62684/159251).* If both truly apply, then you must be asking about some kind of cross-over situation (which [is definitely possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069950/get-an-element-in-a-set-with-member)). There's no Swift or ObjC code in your question, and if you don't care which language is used, then really neither is essential to your problem.

You're asking about an API; that API is accessible in several languages, including ObjC, Swift, C#, and Python. If a MonoTouch dev comes along, she can look at your question and say "You basically have to do the calculation yourself; ask the layout manager for its `foo` and then..." just as well as someone who knows the framework via ObjC or Swift.

Also importantly, long-term, everyone else with the same problem -- including the people using Ruby or [Nu](http://programming.nu/index) when someone gets around to making those work on iOS -- will find answers that just talk in terms of the API more helpful than one that is in a language they don't care to use.

---

*See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289234/

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand a little. Although maybe a MonoTouch dev could tell me that a certain API method won't work, I am still looking for an answer to a specific programming problem. I would really like a Swift answer but I could try to figure out an Objective-C answer if that is all that the person knew. I definitely don't want C# or Python answers, though (unless of course there is just a simple API method name as the answer--is that what you are suggesting?).

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I'm trying to say. My example sentence may be too vague. The solution can be expressed in code, but code is not essential. Any user of Cocoa Touch who knows the answer can tell you "You'll have to get the `NSLayoutManager`'s `foo` property, pass that the `bar` value you're using, then take the return value and calculate the square root of...". Code is just one way to say that. If somebody gives you an all-code answer that's in a language you don't understand, that's clearly an unhelpful answer and you should ask them to clarify (and/or downvote).

Comment: Ok, I can accept that for my particular question. What about in general where code is essential to the answer? If I have a multiline Swift code snippet with some error in it, but I want to express that I will also accept Objective-C (but no other language) answers, how should I tag the question?

Comment: @Suragch Questions like that annoy me. If I have the same issue and I find your question, I don't want to see an answer in some random other language, I want to see a fix to the code that was asked about.

Comment: In that case, @Suragch, understanding Swift is essential to the question: you must be able to read Swift to grasp the problem; thus tag it with [swift]. If a fix to your Swift code in ObjC is for some reason acceptable, then mention that in the question body.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, annoying though it might be, Swift and Objective-C answers are often intermixed, and creating a new Swift version of an old Objective-C question has generally been frowned on by the high rep Objective-C users.

Comment: Lots of discussion both for and against the frowning at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285258/603977, @Suragch.