# Answer edited by a "fan" to include more code

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

If you look at the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17884863/revisions) for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17884863/5620297), it has been edited, adding another big block of code with the edit summary *"Edited by fan of the answer ..."*.

I guess this would be okay if it was a *Community Wiki*, but it isn't, so this should really be its own answer, should it not?

How should I deal with something like this when I see it?

---

Now another question.

I actually came across the above revision / problem when a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11910584) popped up for another revision to the same post, made by another user.

I do not know much about programming for iOS, but I do know that the question was for Objective-C, and the guy who proposed the edit added the Swift code (Apple's newer programming language for creating apps, if I am correct).

How should I review this new edit?

Comment: Are you sure the added code is in Swift? Sure looks like Objective-C to me.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi In the suggested edit the guy explicitly stated *Edit: Swift port of above code:*. I know Swift is very closely related to Objective-C, but as I said, I know almost nothing about these languages. I have never programmed using either of them.

Comment: Oh, right, the suggested edit concerns another user. I just rejected it. These are two different problems I'm afraid.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi On what grounds did you reject it. I looked through them all and it doesn't really fit any...

Comment: I voted to reject as "attempt to reply". To me a Swift translation should go in its own answer (assuming it's useful in the first place).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Okay, thanks. I also just rejected it as an *Attempt to Reply*

Comment: I rejected this as well with "Attempt to reply". Edits that are big enough to be their own answer _should_ be.

Comment: "In the general case, I believe one should not add code to an existing answer" OK, so you're utterly wrong.  The notion that you would somehow, or even can, isolate swift/objc in iOS questions is a non-starter, so that's not worth discussing.  {As I mention below, even if the OP had typed the words "you must not mention Swift here!" that would be meaningless.}  Regarding the overall premise of not "adding to answers", the general idea of SO is that anyone can and should edit anything, any time, any where, to improve content, so don't know what to say about that. It's absolutely commonplace.

Comment: "Now another question." - well that's just begging for a Too Broad close reason.

Comment: Closely related: [Did I do the correct thing by significantly editing an existing answer instead of posting a new answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320619)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the first case the question is "display the thumbnail of a selected image which **should be squared** unlike when using `kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform` like Apple's and my own attempt". The original answer does just that, from the center of the image maintaining the image with the same aspect ratio. The new code does exactly the same, even maintaining some of the code structure, but instead of detecting the size of the display port it sets its own size.

The thing here is that it's basically the same answer **improved**. In fact, out of 36 upvotes the answer has 32 were after the edit. That's a whooping **~88% of all the upvotes were cast after the edit**. That's a edit that improved a post, prevented duplicates and the user [Clever Error](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385017/clever-error) has tactility approved as the edit hasn't been rolled back in all these *years* (last seen 19 hours ago).

---

The new edit should been rejected. Sounds crazy since I defended an edit above, right? Well, in this case the grounds are more simple. The question specify that the user is using Objective-C, the addition is Swift (unlike the first edit).

Comment: The number of votes has nothing to do with the original poster approving of the edit.

Comment: @Braiam, consider - it is now *absolutely commonplace* that basically *every* iOS question contains a mix of objC and swift content.  you would have to delete 10s of thousands of items ... it's also ubiquitous that people are adding "and here's the swift version!" to very old QA.

Comment: note too that the question merely happened to *have* the objC tag.  in no sense did the question even mention objectiveC, and certainly not did it say "absolutely no Swift to be mentioned here".  Additionally, if the OP had written "absolutely no Swift to be mentioned here" what would that mean? everyone would just ignore it and provide relevant iOS content. In 5 years when Swift is dusty history there will be all sorts of other content on there.

Comment: @Lundin where I'm saying that?

Comment: not that any of this matters - and of course, anyone can and should edit anything they want to improve content.  @Lundin you mention "has nothing to do with the original poster approving of the edit".  Note that (a) the original writer has absolutely no moral, legal or technical "rights" over the post.  anyone can and shoudl edit it any time they want.  Braiam has edited it just now - **and that's great**.

Comment: @JoeBlow having a objetive c tag normally means "the answer has to be on objetive c" according to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285258/792066 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315716/792066 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285258/792066

Comment: it has an iOS tag, it's an iOS question.  (in the incredibly obscure case of a question about objC language law or something - whatever.)  Next time I have a spare 500 man-years I'll get to work removing all Swift mentions from iOS questions.  try to *find* a remaining old iOS question where people do not now just answer discussing swift (and, in 5, 10, 50 years, whatever "iOS" is up to then).  it's just silly. thanks for the discussion.

Comment: @JoeBlow No, this is not Wikipedia. You shouldn't go around and toss in random "good stuff" in other people's posts. Edits are for clarification, grammar & spelling, formatting etc. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: @Lundin you harakiri yourself just now: **this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that *needs improvement*, click edit!**

Comment: @Braiam Keep reading past the first sentence. The difference between SO and Wikipedia is that the purpose of the former is to post on-topic answers to narrow, technical questions, while the purpose of latter is to publish broad, complete encyclopedia articles.

Comment: @Lundin well, I did read that, and many more like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066. I see nothing at all that says that edits that improves or expands the existing answer should be denied. For me, that position is just a [weird fetishism of some users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316832/792066).

Comment: @JoeBlow sorry, but as you have seen in my answer I read the question as "I have objective c code, it doesn't do what I want, I want it to do what I want". If you don't agree with that, **edit the question**.

Comment: hi @Braiam you say, *"I read the question as..."*  Yes, absolutely fantastic, as I've said I totally agree that you can and should edit the page as you see fit.  I have no "conceptual" problem with you editing / removing / undoing my work there or anywhere.  {I happen to, at first glance, disagree with you; (i) my addition was staggeringly awesome and incredibly important (on top of a really superb original answer), (ii) as I have said for me the 'objC' distinction is meaningless on the site; but...} as another expert user I never "re-edit" when someone else edits: I just ....

Comment: ... accept you're more on top of it than me, and I never undo edits.  (In the first instance I'd have to look in to the whole issue and think it over for tens of minutes / hours; so again as I say I never undo edits when someone has edited me.)

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm not sure what are you arguing with me about? I said that *your* edit was a improvement. The new one went beyond a "improvement".

Comment: No, I 'm not arguing - sorry for all the double-negaitves.   :)  I'm in absolute agreement with you.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite funny. On the one hand you complain about a user adding a "stand-alone"-answer to an existing one, and on the other hand you **post two different questions as one** on Meta.

Now, to the question (1): Yes, in my opinion it should have been posted as a separate answer.

Also, calling out a user is generally disapproved if it is not explicitly required for the question to make sense since it can impact the users reputation quite heavily (and unfairly), see [What is the Meta-Effect?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) for more informations.

Comment: I do realize the irony! I called out the user since he only edited the question, and so he cannot really be subject to downvotes (apart from dedicated users that go to his user profile, then look at his posts..... etc). It should be posted as a separate answer, but if I do that then it is not his answer. Should I post is as a CW?

Comment: @Druzion That's - IMHO - completely up to you. I'd do this in 2 steps, by first trying to get a hold of him via his latest activity (by leaving a comment on that question/answer). If that does not work out, I'd rollback that edit and post it as CW.

And edit your question, split it into two threads, leaving the first part here. :)

Comment: FWIW if someone goes to their profile and starts downvoting that's crossed the line from Meta Effect to serial voting, the latter of which is illicit and reversed by a daily(?) script.

Comment: @Druzion: You can get ahold of a user by using the "@" syntax to address him/her in a comment. You can use the "@" syntax to address the OP of the post on which you are commenting, or any editor of this post, or any other commenter of this post.