# Did I do the correct thing by significantly editing an existing answer instead of posting a new answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

**Edit:**

Based on the comments (thanks) I posted my solution as a separate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36485266/1052697

**Original question:**

[This Android answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10751989/4) has some major flaws in it, because it can cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when pasting text with multiple new-line characters.

> *"Copy pasting from Stack Overflow danger ahead"*

Because the answer has quite some up-votes (and apparently many people use the code provided as it is) I decided to edit it ([edited version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10751989/revisions)).

The edits I made are in my opinion quite significant, the complete code logic has been changed. Now I'm wondering if I did the right thing. The answer also originally stated the following:

> This solution was created in collaboration with Mobile Identity:
>   http://www.mobile-identity.com/

*Which isn't the best online advertisement for Mobile Identity...*

Anyway, I also decided to remove the statement. As it does not contribute to the answer nor is it needed. I Also removed it because non of the original code-logic stayed the same (so any credit to Mobile Identity seems to be out of place).

**Did I do the right thing? Should I have posted a completely new answer?**

Comment: That seems like a significant change to the answer and not what the original author intended.

Comment: Looks like you turned it into a completely different answer. I suggest rolling those changes back. Then post a comment under the original answer outlining the issue, upvote other comments, and submit a new solution. It wasn't your edit which was upvoted, it was the original.

Comment: `This solution was created in collaboration with Mobile Identity: http://www.mobile-identity.com/` - this is back in since the last rollback - is this.. ok? I wouldn't have thought this was ok. Edit: I'll try removing it and see if it's accepted.

Comment: related: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773) (luckily, voting at [per-site-meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/per-site-meta) doesn't really impact reputation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not okay to just replace someone else's answer with your own.  If you feel that there is a problem with their answer, feel free to vote accordingly and/or comment on the answer explaining what problems it has.  If you have your own solution that you feel is better, post it as a new answer.

Edits exist to improve the presentation of someone else's solution, not to change someone else's solution to your own.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I posted my solution as a separate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36485266/1052697