# Do tags indicate intent or fact?

Tags: support, tags

Lets say I find a question about ios app development about something general like "How do I show a movie?". The OP has posted their attempt in a specific language (lets say obj-c)

Obviously this question should have the obj-c tag. However, is it proper usage if the question also has a swift tag, indicating that the OP is ok with answers in swift, or is it incorrectly tagged because the question contains no swift (example was in obj-c).

Objective-c and swift are very close, but one could image the same thing applied to .net languages, things that run on the JVM, javascript variants etc. If obj-c and swift are ok, how far do you have to go before it isn't?

Related, possibly answered by: [Should [swift] and [objective-c] tags never be used together?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315714/should-swift-and-objective-c-tags-never-be-used-together)

**TLDR**: Are tags for finding questions specific to a language, or are they there to express what languages OP is ok with the answers being in?

Comment: **TLDR**: Yes. (SCNR.)

Comment: Well if we forget that your example is something completely too broad that shouldn't be on the site... if it's on a valid question, yes swift should be fine to indicate if you are okay with swift.

Comment: Well, we can't simply forget that your example is too broad for the site. That is the root of the problem here. If your question was narrowly- (appropriately-) scoped, then it would be trivial to choose the correct tag.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree my chosen example wasn't a good one, but it is possible to have question which can apply to multiple languages and still be specific and on topic, and it was that which I was going for.

Comment: Tags are for what the question is about. It's a way to categorize the question into easy to grasp categories. Being unable to decide what tags to use is often a sign that the question should be refactored. If the question is about "playing a movie" and shows an attempt in Objective-C, then the Swift tag would be off-topic. Unless OP *specifies in their question* that "This project is in Objective-C but if you have a solution in Swift I can also read it", then yes they can add the Swift tag to their Objective-C question. IMO.

Comment: Sure. If the question is on-topic and truly applies to multiple languages, then use both tags. But this is relatively rare for good, on-topic, narrowly-scoped questions.