# Rejected edit: Are tags supposed to be about the problem or just about what the user thought was the problem?

Tags: discussion, tags, rejected-edits

I answered and edited [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306256/error-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-touchtracking-touchtrackingpoint-to-xama)

[The edit was rejected.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23685884)  The reason given was "This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question."

The tags the question had were "xamarin" and "skiasharp"

The tags I set were "c#" for the language, and "casting" because that's the real problem.

The problem itself isn't specific to either xamarin or skiasharp.  It is plain and simple "don't know when to expicitly cast a variable."

The error message is a standard error that you get when you try to assign a variable of one type to a variable of another type without a proper cast.

The error is "Cannot implicitly convert type X to type Y."  The answer is independent of the types - you just need a proper cast, and you really need to understand why you got that error.

So, my question is:

Do tags apply to the real causes of the problem, or do they apply to what the asker thinks is the problem?

Comment: As an aside, I really wanted to flag the question as duplicate because it really is a common and simple mistake.  I couldn't find a clear answer to refer to about the "Cannot implicitly convert" error.  I found 576.1 gazzilion similar questions about "Cannot implicitly convert type Transmogrifier to type Fuzzwarper," but nothing that looked like it hit the real core of the matter.

Comment: If anything, I would have left the original tags as those are not wrong.

Comment: @rene:  Well, that's the question as far as I'm concerned.  The original tags don't give any information that will help the next searcher find it.  The problem isn't in xamarin, and it isn't in skiasharp.  It's a general thing that applies to many things.  In this case, the wording of the error is specific to C#, and the cause is a casting error.

Comment: Just close against this https://stackoverflow.com/q/3757858/792066

Comment: I can't judge if the context is *ONLY* C# casting. Maybe Xamarin has a nice BetterPoint type that no one in C# and casting has ever heard of. You want to brimg that question under the eyes of all experts that might know the answer. That doesn't seem to be limited to only C# and casting experts.

Comment: And then it is indeed a common problem that might not need an edit but just a close as duplicate. Then you don't need the edit and future visitors would still find their answer.

Comment: @Braiam:  That looks good.  I'll flag the one I answered as a duplicate.

Comment: @rene:  That's just the point.  The error straight up tells you that you are trying to assign TypeA to TypeB, and that you need an explicit cast if you want to do it.  This happens **all** the time.  You see the error, you think "oh, wrong types" then you check the types and if they are compatible and either cast it or copy values as needed.  This is all day, every day normal thing to do - for a C# programmer.

Comment: @JRE never happens to me. Anyway. I can't find that type `TouchTrackingPoint` with my Google skills so it is unlikely that a direct cast will solve their issue, nor will any of the answers in the duplicate. Maybe a Xamarin expert does know where this went wrong but it is probably not caused by anything we look at. Luckily the question is still tagged correctly.

Comment: @rene:  I know diddly squat about xamarin, but the cause and solution are still clear.  If you can't cast, you just need to copy the values from one variable to the other - or use them directly, as could be done in this case.  VisualStudio will even tell you if the cast is allowed.

Comment: We can keep arguing forever. Visual Studio won't tell them why they got that strange type there in the first place and you won't know for sure if that type even has properties that would reasonably map to that X and Y. Based on naming it is a good guess but I consider a good guess not an answer. The root cause of their error is still a mystery. Let's move on.

Comment: I think I had a similar question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339947/1456253

Comment: @rene:  The decision whether two types are compatible doesn't depend on property names, or property types.  Is is based on the inheritance of the classes.  In the question we are talking about, if "TouchTracking.TouchTrackingPoint" and "Xamarin.Forms.Point" both inherit from, for example, "System.Drawing.Point" then you could validly cast among those types.

Comment: @JRE I know how the type system in .Net works. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [*Tagging a question based on its answers*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252079/2751851)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your specific issue - as been said in the comment - you can flag it as duplicate.

Generally, I think **both type of tag should be on the answer**. I believe it is obvious why the tags should apply to the real cause of the problem (as adding them makes the question clearer) . On the other hand, having tags that reflecting what the asker though the problem is may make the post easier to find by future user with the same problem.

Having said that, I personally prefer keep the original tags of the post owner and **add** tags that reflect the actual problem (as long as it below 5 tags)

Comment: I've already flagged it as duplicate, and referred to the question that Braiam found.