# Misuse of language tags (here: Objective-C)

Tags: feature-request

I searched for a Q to this topic, but didn't found one. I'm surprised about that, so mark this Q as duplicate, if I failed to find it.

Many questions are tagged with a language tag, even the question does not directly deal with the language. Being an OS X / Cocoa / Objective-C developer I find many questions related to Cocoa tagged with Objective-C, even there is no close relation to the programming language. Users seem to use the tag as a "I want an answer in that language" request. (Actually there is a second programming language, Swift, to use with Cocoa, but I saw this behaviour in the past as well, when there was no Swift.)

I find myself searching for new questions by using this tag. (It seems to be more successful than searching for Cocoa, what would be correct.)

Even it is a misuse of the tag, this usage is widespread.

Some comments let me think, that it is not only widespread, but misunderstood by most users. It is simply incorrect to use a [Swift] or [Objective-C] tag in a question that is related to Cocoa only. This is quite clear, if you read the tag wiki for Objective-C …

> This tag should *be used only on questions that are about Objective-C features* or depend on code in the language. The tags *[cocoa] and [cocoa-touch] should be used to ask about Apple's frameworks or classes*.

… and Swift:

> Swift is an application and systems programming language developed by Apple and distributed as open source. Use this *tag only for questions that are specific to Swift language features*, or those that require code in the language. *Use the related tags [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx), [apple-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch), [tag: tvos], [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch), and [cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa) for (language-agnostic) questions about the platforms or frameworks.*

Should SO introduce a "language" property to every question to stop the misuse of the tag?

BTW: This is how SO works. There has never been a tag for a way an answer has to be given. There are only tags for the relationship of the question.

Comment: "Users seem to use the tag as a 'I want an answer in that language' request." Isn't that kind of the point? Or are you saying questions that purely involve IB or some other tool outside of a coding context are being tagged [obj-c]?

Comment: They have Qs about a part of Cocoa, i. e. view drawing, file management, printing or whatever, and want an answer with code in Objective-C (or Swift). But it is not a Q related to Objective-C itself (control structures, syntax, typing or whatever).

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558771/uitableviewcell-how-to-add-constraint-to-uitextview-before-heightforrowatindex The Q deals with views – a part of Cocoa – and has no relationship to Objective-C itself. The answer could be given with Objective-C or Swift code. However, the Objective-C tag is obviously used to chose the programming language for Q&A, even the Q is programming language agnostic.

Comment: And again, I ask, is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: ??? Of course: *This tag should be used **only on questions that are about Objective-C features or depend on code in the language**. The tags [cocoa] and [cocoa-touch] **should be used to ask about Apple's frameworks or classes**.* [obj-c] should be used for Q like "how do I create an ivar", but not on Qs that has a relation to Cocoa classes as views are.

Comment: Similar points have been raised before: [Should Swift and ObjC tags never be used together?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315714), [Is it acceptable to post answers in Swift on iOS/OS X questions tagged with ObjC?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285258), [What is the cause of so many Swift questions getting tagged with ObjC?] (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312773) I long ago came to the conclusion that this is unenforceable (and [I'm the author of the parts of the tag excerpt](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3625129/13) that you highlighted).

Comment: Hi @JoshCaswell Well, I thought that someone else already had this problem, but I did not find it. However, my Q is, whether it is worth to add a "preferred language" property to a Q without being a tag. Maybe a warning could be applied if some tags are included together like [Objective-C] + [Cocoa]. (Only a warning, because there might be cases, in wich both tags are included correctly.) Actually it is not possible to find Cocoa related Qs without searching for Objective-C and Swift, what is akin of anticonceptual.

Comment: Actually there are 11 featured Qs for Objective-C, 9 for Swift and 0 for Cocoa. I make a bet, that at least 15 of the Qs are related to Cocoa and programming language agnostic.

Comment: Many questions and answers, even though they are about APIs that can be written in different languages, contain code samples. Code is important part of Q/A. Receiving answer in language OP might not be familiar with is not very helpful.

Comment: I don't want my Swift tagged Cocoa questions answered in Objective-C, just as I don't want my Delphi tagged Windows API questions answered in C++, nor my Java tagged Android questions answered in Scala. Or vice versa.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Indeed, this is the reason for my suggestion to add a *property* "preferred language". Using a *tag* objc or swift to mark the preferred language might be helpful, but infringes the SO rules. This conflict let me open the Q.

Comment: But it is not preferred language... it is language I specifically want. "Preferred" means it would be nice to have but not mandatory, and as end result OP could get answer in "wrong" language.

Comment: I don't see the infringement of any SO rules with having specific language tag included with the question. It is relevant tag.

Comment: Please read all comments. I explained that. I will add it to the Q. However, you can mark it "requested". But it is a wrong tag on most Q.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad you should like "android" questions than as they pretty much never tagged with language (irrespective of language used). SO is big and you should be able to find part you like.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, I'm not here to find a part I like, but to work on the part, I can share my knowledge. I cannot say whether it is different or not with other language-framework combinations. However, this is no reason to transfer to another OS.

Comment: When I see questions like that, I down vote the question and ask them to remove the irrelevant tags. If the user does not remove the tags, I move on, however if I see at some point that the user removed the tag, I remove my down vote too, as the reason for my down vote being there is no longer valid. And then I move on. I too am rather annoyed by people misusing tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Stack Overflow community, by popular acclaim and usage, has decided that questions are tagged with the language that the user is using, even if the question is not about the particulars of that language. This is a *fact*.

You can argue against it. You can rail against it. You can write tag wiki entries forbidding it.

But it *will still happen*.

You are not going to get millions of people to only use the Objective-C tag for questions about the language. That ship has sailed, and it sailed long ago.

You can either accept that fact and move on, or argue about it. But nothing you do will change that reality.

Comment: I agree that this will happen in future, *if nobody tries to find a solution.*  However, the solution in my comments to warn for some combinations of tags would be cheap to implement and maybe ease the situation. (I really do not know, whether this problem occurs with other combinations of tags, too.)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad You would need to make sure the false positive rate is not too much.  You do not want to serve up warnings on perfectly valid questions.

Comment: I think that [swift]+[cocoa] and [objc]+[cocoa] has false positives less than 10 %. However, one of the biggest problem is that very often the language tag is misused *and* the framework tag is omitted. In such cases you have close to no chance.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Less than 10%? That's unacceptably high by at least an order of magnitude.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: "*I agree that this will happen in future*" The future? This has been the way it has been since the site was *founded*. Do you think that `c++` is a tag about the language or about posts written in C++? Do you thin every `c` or `java` question is about language constructs? No, this is the reality of the tag system. And unless you're willing to go through and retag *millions* of questions, it's not changing.

Comment: @NicolBolas … will continue to happen in future. As I said I saw the problem for years. Maybe I'm not fatalistic enough.

Comment: @Deduplicator That morning I had 0 % false positives on the featured Qs. This was only a very careful estimation.

Comment: This is nonsense. I can perfectly well accept the facts while still arguing against them every chance I get!

Comment: @JoshCaswell +1 Indeed, being fatalistic is not the better choice. And the truth has never been democratic as you can see here. So at least it is a proof. However, I have to accept the way it is handled, right or wrong, and continue arguing against it. At the right place and time.

Comment: The description of the tag should be changed.

Comment: @Willeke Yeah, *this* would be a solution. However, the concept of SO is that you tag a Q with a tag that is related to the subject of the Q. Selecting a tag in a search should lead you to Q related to Objective-C, not to Q, with code in Objective-C. Legalizing it would make the mistake formally correct, what is anti-conceptual.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want that API related questions get additional *language tag (property)* separated from current tagging system. Because, by your definition, people abuse language tags when they ask API related questions.

Why I think your request is bad idea:

---

Definition of tag:

> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other,
>   similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to
>   find and answer your question.

Adding separate *language only property* would defy above definition. Questions would no longer be grouped by tags, but by tags and language properties (tags).

- Inevitable question is how pure language questions should be marked then. With language property or tag?
- How many language properties would be allowed - single or multiple ones? There are languages where it is common to add multiple language tags - one generic and one for specific language version.
- How would you force using language property for API questions and not tag?

---

But, more important, you see abuse where there is none (or happens rarely)

Stack Overflow is programming related site. Questions, even API ones, are commonly accompanied with code samples, and so are answers. Code is important part of Q/A process. As end result (of proposed feature), most of the API related questions would get additional language property attached. If you agree that receiving answers in "wrong" language is not very helpful, then the whole separation process is basically useless.

And for those (few) questions that really might be language agnostic and where neither question, nor the answer is in any way code related, you can freely edit the question and remove superfluous tags. That is what editing feature is all about - for correcting and improving.

If you don't agree that receiving code sample in wrong language is not welcomed, then we are dealing with different arguments here.

Different languages can be very different in their nature. Translating code from one into another should not be considered as easy task even for experienced developers. You have to be skilled in both languages to do that job properly. For beginners, struggling with single language, that problem can only be even worse.

To paraphrase, I don't want my Swift tagged Cocoa questions answered in Objective-C, just as I don't want my Delphi tagged Windows API questions answered in C++, nor my Java tagged Android questions answered in Scala. Or vice versa.

---

You have quoted tag wikis to prove abuse

> This tag should be used only on questions that are about Objective-C
>   features or depend on code in the language. The tags [cocoa] and
>   [cocoa-touch] should be used to ask about Apple's frameworks or
>   classes.

While you read above as *don't mark any [cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa) or [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) question with [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) or [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tags* I read it as *you can mark [cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa) or [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) questions with [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) or [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tags if there is code involved*, and usually there is code involved.

I would say that abuse here is subject to interpretation. And yours is very strict one.

Comment: 1. a) Pure language Qs has to be marked with a tag. That's obvious. b) Multiple including 0. c) Actually it is not possible to edit the Q to correct the wrong use. I see that happening several times. But since this mistake is widely spreaded, editing leads to the result that you have 3 tags to search for simple Cocoa Qs. 2. It is not a few. For Cocoa it is more than 80 %. I posted a example in my comments. Please read the comments. 3. Your answer assumes that there is no other way to mark a PL. I want that feature. What you want is simple a continuation of infringement of the SO rules.

Comment: No, the meaning is not "if there is any code involved." The meaning is, that the involved code in the tagged PL is important for the Q&A. Obviously otherwise language tags has to be set nearly for every Q, what is not the sense of tags including language tags.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I have read the comments - your example is very poor one. There is Objective-C code in both question and answers, even though it is not complex one.

Comment: BTW: In the comments I made the additional suggestion to at least display a warning, if there is a combination of tags that typically is misused, i. e. [objective-c]+[cocoa] or [swift]+[cocoa]. I do not know, whether this problem occurs with other combinations, too.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I said "can mark" not "must mark". Language tag is optional, but it can also be included if OP wishes to include it.

Comment: 1. The fact, that there is code, does not trigger the tag. Probably there are integers used in that code. Do you want to tag it with [integer]? Maybe there are floats in that code. Do you want to tag it with [float]? You have to decorate a Q with a tag, if the Q itself is related to a topic dealing specifically with the tag subject. 2. My example is not poor. You can recheck it every moment on SO.

Comment: No, the correctness of a tagging does not depend on the questioner's choice, but on the subject of the Q. Otherwise it would be forbidden to edit the tagging. BTW: The trigger for my Q was that somebody else (a well-known user) removed a language tag on a Cocoa Q. He did that correctly.

Comment: Point is that this is programming site, we use programming languages, and language tags carry more weight than some other tags. Even though you ask API question, usually solving your API problem involves using specific programming language, so yes language tag is relevant to the question.

Comment: Ah, then [statement], [compiler], [linker], … is valid for every Q on SO. Hmmmm …

Comment: That is not what I am saying...

Comment: Of course, but it is the logical consequence of what you are saying. *Even though you ask API question, usually solving your API problem involves using specific programming language, so yes language tag is relevant to the question.* Even though you ask API question, usually solving your API problem involves using a compiler, so yes compiler tag is relevant to the question.

Comment: If you cannot see how is language tag relevant and all other tags you mention are not, then I really cannot help you, nor I see the point in continuing this discussion.

Comment: Aha. Maybe it is difficult to explain the difference, if there is none.